# Can different users share the same login (html) page, (to enter a private html page)?

Tags: html, .htaccess, authentication

I  have an html page with images, where the user selcts their image, enters there login details and is taken to their own (html) invoice page. I have done this using htaccess password protection. It seems to work well except, in testing, if I switch between different logins, they stop loading, and the site becomes inaccesible. This happens whether I make successful logins or purposely failed attempts.

This is my ht access code

```
# basic password protection
<IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
AuthUserFile /home/site/.htpasswds/user/.htpasswd
 AuthName "Name and password required."
 AuthType Basic
 <Limit GET POST>
  Require valid-user
 </Limit>
</IfModule>
```

So is there a better method to achieve what I am currently doing but without my site crashing?

Comment: htaccess is the best method for this purpose. You should use some server side scripting like php, or file format system to authenticate users

Comment: Thank you. So now I have attached a login form to each image that uses php to direct  user to their page. however, because I have multiple images, several forms can end up being open at once. Which may be unlikely to happen but I would like it to keep things tidy. So I have put up another question that I need help with here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384003/use-javascript-to-close-any-forms-before-opening-a-new-one), as I need help with javascript to close surplus forms.