# Use javascript to close all opened forms before opening a new one

Tags: javascript, html, forms, authentication

I'm making an html page with images, where the user clicks their image, to log in to their invoice page. This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function showHideForm(formid) 
    {
       var _form = document.getElementById(formid);
      _form.style.display = (_form.style.display != "block") ? "block" : "none";
       return false;
    }
</script>

<p>
  <a href="#" onclick="return showHideForm('hiddenForm1');">
    <img src="" width="150" height=    "150" />
  </a>
</p>
<form  id="hiddenForm1" style="display: none;" method="post" action="user1_login.php">
  <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Name" required /><br />
  <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required/><br />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<p>
  <a href="#" onclick="return showHideForm('hiddenForm2');">
    <img src=""  width="150" height="150" />
  </a>
</p>
<form  id="hiddenForm2" style="display: none;" method="post" action="user2_login.php">
  <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Name" required /><br />
  <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required/><br />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

It works nicely except that if you click on other images, you get several instances open at the same time.

Is it possible to tack a bit of code to the beginning of the javascript to close any open instances before it runs the code to open a new form?

Comment: What other images you are talking about. It works fine as expected.

Comment: Yes it does work well. I have put up two images to show what is happening, but in reality I will have a page of at least 20 images. If someone clicks on the wrong link or is just trying it out, the page will be littered with open forms. I just want it to be tidy. (If that is possible).

Comment: give me some time to answer.

Comment: Are you free to use jQuery?

Comment: you want the answer in jquery or plain javascript?

Comment: I haven't used jquery before. If I can make it work, either is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is simple, have a class for openedform. On click event remove that class from the existing  opened forms and add the class to the currently clicked form. Here is how to do it with jquery.

```
 function showHideForm(formid) 
 {
    // var _form=$("#"+formid);  (in jquery)

    var _form =document.getElementById(formid);
    //select all existing opened forms and remove the class
    $('.openedForm').removeClass('openedForm');
    //add the openedForm class to the currently clicked 
    $(_form).addClass('openedForm');
    return false;
 }
```

Add the following code into your css file.

```
  .openedForm
     {
        display:block !important;
     }
```

If you need to alter the css of elements using javascript try to use classes. This way you make your javascript code cleaner and readable and your styling logic stays separated from the main logic.
Avoid using inline styles as much as possible.

Working demo:
https://jsbin.com/nigivu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: If this solves your problem then please acknowledge my effort by accepting the answer. This keeps me motivated. If any doubt feel free to ask

Comment: Brilliant. That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Comment: I would be thankful if you accept the answer as solution.

Comment: i can't see how to do that

Comment: I have ticked. I think that is correct, but takes 24 hours to come up.